# Is using Transaction APIs mandatory for a bank Action for Google Assistant?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, banking

I work for a bank. We developed an Action for Google Assistant which also enables the user to top up his/her debit card by moving a pre-defined amount of money from his/her bank account. No third parts are involved, and all the logic is within the bank's servers via APIs.
The question is whether we should use Transaction APIs or not. We do not sell goods or services via the Action.
The problem is that Transaction APIs are not available in our country.
Thank you,
Roberto

Comment: drop a mail to Actions-on-Google supports team.

Comment: I did this. They replied by copying and pasting what's written on the Action on Google page.

Comment: Since it is not available in your country they should not reject your app when released. I faced a similar issue where we were asked to add transaction API as we were doing reservations and app was US based.

Comment: Try and post on Google Plus group https://plus.google.com/communities/105684267327487893574 and tag moderators.

Comment: Thank you Abhinav! Here is the post https://plus.google.com/u/1/110592038839862015042/posts/7trDkBQTy7H But how to tag moderators?

Comment: I tagged them, let's wait.

Comment: I saw that. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem.
Google answered me that Transaction APIs are not required for bank implementations.
Thank you for your help!
Roberto